# ReactiveMongoRepository not saving my data

Tags: database, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, reactor

I am noob in `spring` and `mongo` and `noSQL`.

I have connected to my mongoDB on local.

However my attempts to save my entity keeps failing.

```
val a0 = myEntity(name = "my Entity")
repository.save(a0)
```

My repository extends `ReactiveMongoRepository<MyEntity, Long>`.

But when I change it to extend `MongoRepository<MyEntity, Long>`, then it works.

What possibly could be the problem?

My database instance is running and working fine.
I am guessing that it has to do something with reactive things.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use reactive streams, you should be aware that [nothing happens until you subscribe](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe):

> In Reactor, when you write a `Publisher` chain, data does not start pumping into it by default. Instead, you create an abstract description of your asynchronous process (which can help with reusability and composition).
>
> By the act of **subscribing**, you tie the `Publisher` to a `Subscriber`, which triggers the flow of data in the whole chain. This is achieved internally by a single request signal from the `Subscriber` that is propagated upstream, all the way back to the source `Publisher`.

That means that if you use `ReactiveMongoRepository`, somewhere along the line you have to subscribe to your reactive stream. This can be done by using the `subscribe()` method on any `Publisher`. For example, using Java, that would be:

```java
reactiveRepository
    .save(myEntity)
    .subscribe(result => log.info("Entity has been saved: {}", result));
```

Additionally, frameworks like Webflux will handle the subscription for you if you write reactive controllers. Using Java that means you could write something like:

```java
@GetMapping
public Mono<MyEntity> save() {
    return reactiveRepository.save(myEntity); // subscribe() is done by the Webflux framework
}
```

Obviously, there's a lot more to reactive programming than just that, and you should be aware that you cannot simply swap `MongoRepository` to `ReactiveMongoRepository` without adapting to the reactive ecosystem and using reactive programming.

There's an [Introduction to Reactive Programming](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive) chapter within the Reactor reference guide that might be interesting to read. The earlier quoted documentation also comes from this chapter of the reference guide.

Comment: But this way you will get `Disposable` from `subscribe()` whereas repository returns `Mono`. How to pass POJO to be saved and get `Mono` of saved entity?

Comment: @Zon I don't understand your question. If you want to return a `Mono` from your code, then return the `repository.save()` call without calling `subscribe()`. Just be aware that the code that calls your logic eventually has to subscribe somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

To make you stream terminal with `subscribe()` operation and to get the `Mono` result at the same time - split into two separate operations:

```
val a0 = myEntity(name = "my Entity");
Mono<?> savedEntity = repository.save(a0);
savedEntity.subscribe();
return savedEntity;
```